Mr. Potter in "It's a Wonderful Life"
In "It's a Wonderful Life," Uncle Billy accidentally gives Mr. Potter the deposit money for the week instead of the banker. This leads to an auditing issue, but more importantly what legal issues would Mr. Potter be in if he were to keep the money?
Later on in the film there is a scene where George goes over to Mr. Potter and tells him the $8000 is missing. Further, Potter observed Uncle Billy clearly panicked about the deposit and knew of the issue that the money was misplaced. Lastly, as he is a board member of the building and loan company, and the owner of the bank, it would seem that to keep quiet about the money would not just be unethical but would imply some type of liability of not bringing the $8000 to the police at a minimum.
Uncle Billy is usually described as being in some type of legal trouble for misplacing funds, but what would happen to Potter?

Theft by finding
If you find something belonging to somebody else and keep it, you’re guilty of theft.
Fraud
Beyond that, Potter knows who the money belongs to and, instead of returning it, as was his initial impulse, he dishonesty keeps it to cause harm to somebody else - that’s fraud
Breach of director’s duties
As a director of the Savings & Loan, Potter has a duty to put its interest before any personal interest - he didn’t do that.

I don't agree with fraud.  It's lacking the element of deception as a cause of the money transfer.

@MichaelHall Taking the money isn’t the fraud - causing the harm that keeping the money is - the collapse of the S&L and jail for its managers. There’s certainly deception in that, especially since as I recall, Patter was explicitly asked about the envelope and denied having seen it.

But by that definition what is NOT a fraud?  If any and every crime followed by denial after the fact is considered fraud, then why does it have its own definition?  No, fraud requires some forethought and deception that is lacking in this example.

@MichaelHall "“Fraud” is any activity that relies on deception in order to achieve a gain. Fraud becomes a crime when it is a “knowing misrepresentation of the truth or concealment of a material fact to induce another to act to his or her detriment” (Black’s Law Dictionary)" (link) If he lied with the intent of causing the other person to not be able to recover the money due to their mistaken belief based on said lie (rather than him merely avoiding an admission of guilt on his part), that does seem to constitute fraud.

@Flater fraud also includes causing loss to another even without gain to the perpetrator (or anyone)

@DaleM: Sure, but that seems an irrelevant edge case if Potter actually received the money.

@MichaelHall: Hence my distinction between doing it to evade blame, versus doing it to actively steer the other person in the wrong direction with the intention of that direction causing them additional harm. For example, if a company does something with the intent to cause the user to unwittingly break the warranty seal on the product (thus now letting the company off the hook for warranty claims), that constitutes fraud. Not because the company initially lied about the original claim not falling under warranty, but because the company actively did something to trick the customer into a loss.

@Flater, there are two key elements in this definition.  First, Potter never misrepresents himself.  Second,  "to induce another to act to his or her detriment". These two elements are missing in this scenario.

@MichaelHall: If Potter's sole intention was to evade blame, I agree this does not constitute fraud. However, while I don't remember the movie that well, but if there was any further action on Potter's part in order to further him retaining the money (and by extension deprive others of it), would be an act of defrauding these individuals. An absence of alerting others that you've wrongly received money is one thing (still illegal, i.e. theft by finding, but not fraud). Taking actions to actively obfuscate it is another (which does start constituting fraud).

@MichaelHall "Potter never misrepresents himself" The definition of fraud does not refer to misrepresenting yourself, it refers to misrepresenting or concealing the truth. This doesn't require you to actively converse with someone and lie to them. It requires you to take active steps that help ensure the truth does not come to light, in a way that negatively impacts another. This is different from e.g. a violent crime, in that you could return the money, but you couldn't undo the violence even if you admitted to it. Further action taken to avoid returning the money is a continued crime.

@Flater, allow me to prephrase:  Potter never misrepresents the truth in order to induce another to act...  One must lead to another in order for it to be fraud.  It's right there in definition you provided, and I don't know how to make it more clear.

@MichaelHall: Potter threatened swearing an arrest warrant on George for misappropriation for funds while having knowingly pocketed the money in an earlier scene, and seeing Billy looking for it. Tell me that that's not fraudulent. Full script here

@MichaelHall: Oh and by the way Potter actually actioned his threat, these were not hollow words. That sheriff was very much acting on the basis of Potter's claims, which were disingenuous, and Potter's express intent was to punish and imprison George based on the missing funds.

Worth noting that he doesn't owe duties as a shareholder, even though he does as a director. Shareholders have basically no duties to anyone (except in the case of an abuse of a minority shareholder by a majority shareholder in a closely held company).

@Flater, I have seen the movie and agree Potter's actions were illegal, but none of his misrepresentations induced uncle Billy to act to place the money into a folded newspaper and give it to Potter.  They all happened after the fact.  Perjury, obstruction of justice, defamation, conspiracy, theft...  there are many possible charges for Potter, just not fraud.  The definition is clear and that's all I have to say on the matter.  Happy Holidays!
